# How to use Nginx Reverse Proxy redirect

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

i want use nginx reserve proxy but I want to use it like this.

http://example.com/redirect/http://google.com/search?q=1

I want to redirect the link that comes after the redirect article to that link completely with the referrer, origin information I specified.

Could you please let me know how do I do this?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) You should not just request a ready solution. SO is for helping solve specific errors, after you've shown your effort solving them

Comment: @Ron Thank you for your reply.  I tried many methods, I tried with regex, but it didn't work.  When I give the url manually, there is no problem, but I want to capture the url in the incoming link.  so i couldn't and asked here.

Comment: Please take some time to read the link I posted.. you need to provide a reproducible example, along with the EXACT error you are trying to solve... we right now an only guess what you've tried and what was the exact outcome, and what your exact goal is... Also for this issue there are ton of examples online, how much of a research did you do, what exactly did you try? ALL of this should be in your Question